# Java Firing ActionEvent

Tags: java, timer, actionevent

I've seen posts like this before but the questions or the answers are unclear, so bear with me if you've heard this before. I have a timer and I want an ActionEvent to occur when the timer is set off. I don't want to use the javax.swing.Timer method. How can this be done? It is not necessary to explain but that would be helpful. I'm looking for something like an  *ActionEvent.do()* method

My Code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param millisec time in milliseconds
 * @param ae action to occur when time is complete
 */
public BasicTimer(int millisec, ActionEvent ae){
    this.millisec = millisec;
    this.ae = ae;
}

public void start(){
    millisec += System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }while(current < millisec);

}
```

Thanks! Dando18

Comment: *"I've seen posts like this before but they are not asked well"* ... what a coincidence ...

Comment: Just use the `Timer`. Your implementation seems single threaded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want to know of a way to do this without the Timer.

Comment: `I'm looking for something like an ActionEvent.do() method` - this is the way the Swing Timer works. Whenever the Timer fires it creates an ActionEvent and then invokes the actionPeformed() method of your ActionListener using this ActionEvent.

Comment: Why _not_ use a Swing Timer?

Comment: I would just spawn a separate thread that keeps a reference to the action event.  In it's run method I would have the spawned thread call Thread.sleep(<time in millis>), and after that it would invoke the action event.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some simple timer implementation. Why you just didn't check how other timers work ?

```
 public class AnotherTimerImpl {

        long milisecondsInterval;
        private ActionListener listener;
        private boolean shouldRun = true;

        private final Object sync = new Object();

        public AnotherTimerImpl(long interval, ActionListener listener) {
            milisecondsInterval = interval;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void start() {
            setShouldRun(true);
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (isShouldRun()) {
                        listener.actionPerformed(null);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(milisecondsInterval);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        public void stop() {
            setShouldRun(false);
        }

        public boolean isShouldRun() {
            synchronized (sync) {
                return shouldRun;
            }
        }

        public void setShouldRun(boolean shouldRun) {
            synchronized (sync) {
                this.shouldRun = shouldRun;
            }
        }

    }
```